# How to efficiently replace arguments in a function?

Tags: r, function, replace, arguments

I'm working on a function that has an argument that can take any combination of value in `0:2`

This argument is based on the "margin" system of `prop.table` function, but extends it so it can take several values: 0 is cell, 1 is row, 2 is column, but 1:2 is row and col and 0:2 is row, column, and cell.

I want to clarify this notation so that `margin` can take its value in `c("all", "line", "column", "cell", 0, 1, 2)`, with last values needed for backward compatibility.

Here is my attempt using a `switch` (which I heard should be avoided):

```
ff = function(x, margin=c("all", "line", "column", "cell", 0, 1, 2)){
    if(!is.numeric(margin)){
        margin = switch(margin,
                        all = 0:2,
                        line = 1,
                        column = 2,
                        cell = 0)
        if(is.null(margin)) margin=0:2 #defaulting 
    }
    margin
}


ff(NULL, margin=1:2)
ff(NULL, margin="all")
ff(NULL, margin="cell")
ff(NULL, margin=c("column", "cell")) #error in switch (EXPR must be a length 1 vector)
```

If margin has an unexpected value, it would default it to 0:2. I'd rather use `match.arg` but I couldn't get it to accept a vector. Moreover, as it is now, the default vector will be coerced to character.

I also thought about replacing "all" by `0:2` etc. and then use `unlist` and `unique` but could not find any list replacement function that worked here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use a named list and then index that list:

```
ff = function(x, margin=c("all", "line", "column", "cell", 0, 1, 2)){
  if(!is.numeric(margin)){
    if(is.null(margin)) {
      margin=0:2 #defaulting 
    } else {
      marginopts = list(all = 0:2,
                        line = 1,
                        column = 2,
                        cell = 0)
      margin <- unname(unlist(marginopts[margin]))
    }
  }
  margin
}
ff(NULL, margin=1:2) # [1] 1 2
ff(NULL, margin="all") # [1] 0 1 2
ff(NULL, margin="cell") # [1] 0
ff(NULL, margin=c("column", "cell")) # [1] 2 0
ff(NULL, margin=NULL) # [1] 0 1 2
```

Hope this helps!